# How to read Redis binary values in redis console

Tags: redis, azure-redis-cache

I store a byte array with 5 bytes in a Redis entry. Writing and reading using a client library works and expected, but when I try to read the value in a Redis console I get something I don't know how to interpret:

```
>get keyHere
"\x02\x8e\x8b\x0cb"
```

There is something I clearly don't understand because `\x0cb` is not a hex value for a byte and there are only 4 `\x` (and I expected 5 for 5 bytes).

Confused, I decided to performed an experiment. I educated myself about how to set raw bytes; I set an entry's value to "\x01\x07" and read it back. I expected "\x01\x07" but the read value is shown as "\x01\a".

```
>set "3" "\x01\x07"
OK
>get 3
"\x01\a"
```

How should I read entries in a Redis cache in the Redis console to see raw bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the byte is not printable, redis-cli prints the hex format, otherwise, it prints the c-escpaped sequence.

> because \x0cb is not a hex value for a byte and there are only 4 \x (and I expected 5 for 5 bytes)

The first 4 bytes are not printable, so they are printed as hex format. The last byte is the `b`, which is printable.

> I expected "\x01\x07" but the read value is shown as "\x01\a".

`\x07`'s c-escaped sequence is `\a`, and is printable.

> How should I read entries in a Redis cache in the Redis console to see raw bytes?

If you need the raw bytes (which might not be printable), you can specify the `--raw` option when running redis-cli.