# Unable to view the byte formatted value from redis-cli

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

My requirement is that in redis db, keys should be stored as strings and values as byte array.
And I am able to achieve the same in java using lettuce's RedisCodec. But when I view the value through reds-cli it appears to be in original string itself rather than the byte format.  Following is the simple code I am trying with.

```
RedisURI redisURI = RedisURI.builder().withHost("localhost")
        .withPort(6379)
        .build();

RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create(redisURI);
RedisCommands<String, byte[]> redisCommands = redisClient.connect(RedisCodec.of(new StringCodec(), new ByteArrayCodec())).sync();

redisCommands.set("key", "value".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println(redisCommands.get("key"));
```

Console O/p : [B@3bd7f8dc

redis-cli o/p:

127.0.0.1:6379> get key

"value"

I am using lettuce as redis client. I am unable to understand why the value I obtained from redis-cli is in string itself rather than the byte format.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was the answer useful to solve your requirement?

Comment: @Alper Derya, provided links didn't answer my question. However, they were informative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that below answer helps you to understand reading byte value from redis-cli.

[How to read Redis binary values in redis console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200069/how-to-read-redis-binary-values-in-redis-console)

Here is also detail explaniton of redis-cli. I hope it makes sense.
https://redis.io/docs/manual/cli/

Answer (score 0):

The second argument from `RedisCodec` is how you will transmit the value data to Redis Server, which in your case is through `ByteArrayCodec`, once it is retrieved using `get` is serialized back to the original form.

Answer (score 0):

What I use to read byte arrays from redis is something like this:

```
byte[] value = redisSyncConnection.get("key");
try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(value);
     ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
     String valueString = (String) ois.readObject();
     System.out.println(valueString);
}
```